# Spotify Web player - previous and next shortcuts

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, spotify

I use keyboard shortcuts for all of my media players, but Spotify's web player (open.spotify.com) seems to be pretty limited in the keyboard shortcuts it provides.

I know that [<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>left/right arrow</kbd> works in Spotify's app](https://support.spotify.com/is/using_spotify/system_settings/keyboard-shortcuts/) to skip to the next or previous track, but is there an equivalent for their web player?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of a way to do this natively on Spotify's web player, but I created a userscript to allow the left and right keys go to the previous and next tracks, respectively (no <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> or anything needed).

You can install it through [GreasyFork](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/375100-next-and-previous-key-shortcuts-for-spotify) or copy-paste it below:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Next and Previous key shortcuts for Spotify
// @description  Allows the left and right keyboard arrows to be used to go to the previous and next songs on Spotify.
// @author       Zach Saucier
// @namespace    https://zachsaucier.com/
// @version      1.1
// @match        https://open.spotify.com/*
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';
    window.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
        switch(event.code) {
            case 'ArrowLeft':
                document.querySelector('.spoticon-skip-back-16').click();
                break;
            case 'ArrowRight':
                document.querySelector('.spoticon-skip-forward-16').click();
                break;
        }
    }, false);
})();
```